# Implementing Nested Switch Controller in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jsr223

I have a JSR223 Sampler where i am getting two values and based on that two values, i have to make nested Switch controller ,

```
vars.put('counts',new 
groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).options.size() as 
String)

if (Count==1) {
vars.put('Opt', 'Single')
} else {
vars.put('Opt', 'double')
}

def size = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), 
'$.options_available')
if (size == []) {
vars.put('size', 'NonConfigurable')
} else {
vars.put('size', 'Configurable')
}
```

if  count ==1 , then control should be Configurable -> Single Controller
if count==2 , then control should be Configurable -> Double Controller

How to implement the above case with nested Switch controller in Jmeter ? Help is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a single [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) should be enough, just use `${Opt}-${size}` as "Switch Value" and create the following switch branches:

- Single-Configurable
- Single-NonConfigurable
- double-Configurable
- double-NonConfigurable

[image: JMeter Switch Controller]

Also be aware that if certain actions assume shared test elements which are applicable for > 1 switch branch you can consider using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) to avoid code duplication.